# Did DC officials ever acknowledge the term "Arrowverse" for their canon universe?

Tags: production, terminology, arrowverse

Did officials ever confirm or acknowledge the term  [Arrowverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowverse) for their DC shows (consisting of Arrow, The Flash, Vixen and Legends of Tomorrow)?

"Arrowverse" and "Flarrow/Flarrowverse" were famous terms used by fans but now *Arrowverse* seems to have gained acceptance as the official name.

**But did any DC official also acknowledge this name?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they have, though the spelling seems inconsistent.

Yes. When discussing *Supergirl* early on, Andrew Kreisberg (a producer on all the Arrowverse shows plus *Supergirl*) used the phrase, though he hyphenated it:

> And quite frankly, just making the Arrow-verse, which is what we call Legends, Flash and Arrow work and then making Supergirl work, it's enough of a challenge without having to add a fourth player." <sup>[src](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/supergirl-flash-ep-shoots-down-845560)</sup>

Most other media outlets have been using the term since *Flash* premiered, without the hyphen, and the showrunners seem to have been going along with it. For example, during the promotion for the introduction of *Vixen* to the CW Seed online network, Mark Guggenheim (who is one of the producers of *Arrow*, as well as a long-time writer for DC comics) retweeted a bleedingcool.com story:

> The Arrowverse Grows As The Animated Vixen Series Is About To Begin <sup>[src](https://twitter.com/mguggenheim/status/635191474037002240)</sup>

Guggenheim himself later repeated the term "Arrowverse" in a promotional Video for *Vixen*

> "Vixen. An animated series that takes place within the Arrowverse"<sup>[src](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1GOM-kNjq8)</sup>

It's obviously impossible to tell from the spoken word how to "spell" it, but he seemed to say it as just one word, not two.

---

As @cde points out, the showrunners have also used the term **Flarrow** to describe their universe, e.g. when discussing the first big two-part crossover:

> #Flarrow storyboard glimpse <sup>[src](https://twitter.com/mguggenheim/status/540298811835314177)</sup>

and

> It's here!  The #Arrow and #TheFlash CROSSOVER tonight at 8/7c!  Bigger! Faster!  Arrow-y-er!  So excited for you all to see!  #FLARROW <sup>[src](https://twitter.com/ajkreisberg/status/671760502393995264)</sup>

Comment: They also called it ***Flarrow***. We should call it that. http://www.ew.com/article/2016/03/18/supergirl-flash-crossover-spoilers

Comment: Kreisberg also hashtagged #Flarrow https://twitter.com/ajkreisberg/status/671760502393995264 https://twitter.com/search?q=flarrow%20from%3Aajkreisberg&src=typd as did Mark https://twitter.com/search?q=flarrow%20from%3Amguggenheim&src=typd